# Clang " couldn't infer template argument " whereas gcc / g++ can. Which is right?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

I have been trying to compile a project (which is fine using gcc/g++) with clang and compilation stuck on a template invocation.
 I've tried to create the simplest similar piece of code exhibiting the same error message. Here it is:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int A( double in )
{
  return 1;
}

int A( int in )
{
  return 1;
}


template<class M, class T>
M test(T input, M (fun) (T) )
{
  return fun( input );
}



int main( int argc, const char *argv[] )
{
  cout << test( (int) 1, A ) << test( (double) 1.2, A ) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The error from clang (appears twice of course):

```
error: no matching function for call to 'test'
candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'M'
```

Gcc doesn't complain.
Please note M is the return type and is always "int".

Does someone know which is right and why?

Thanks

Comment: did you try using test(..., &A) instead?

Comment: Stefano: I tried, it made no difference.

Comment: And it shouldn't. There's no need to use the address operator on a function name to get the function pointer. (And similarly, there's no need to explicitly dereference a function pointer with `*` to call it.) Although you can if you really want, but it makes no difference.

Comment: point taken, I've never really managed to stick function pointer sintax in my mind. Thanks @BoBTFish

Comment: To whomever might fall on this looking for the error message, it can be resolved specifying the types, i.e.:
    test<int,int>( 1, A )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer (now deleted) was wrong. Clang is wrong.

The compiler should be able to deduce the type `M` because the function argument is `M(fun)(T)`. Note that there is no `M` in the function pointer argument list, so this corresponds to the `T()` (C++11) / `T(*)()` (C++93) in 14.8.2.5:

> where `(T)` represents a *parameter-type-list* where at least one parameter type contains a `T`, and **`()` represents a *parameter-type-list* where no parameter type contains a `T`.**

Comment: +1 because I believe you are correct and this is a clang bug.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `type (T)` to be standard-compliant?

Comment: @maverik - No. Either `T()` or `T(T)` can be used to parse the template type `T`. Note that the `()` does not mean a function that takes no arguments. It simply means that none of the function arguments contains a `T`.

Comment: Please, look at 14.8.2.5 (11): `X<int> (*) (char [6]) is of the form template-name<T> (*) (type [i]) which is a variant of type (*) (T)`. Can we consider the following (about function A): `int A(double) is of the form T (*) (type) which is variant of type (*)(T)` because T is deduced from the first argument of the function `test`?

Comment: Thanks to all of you.
The document you refer to is this one:
http://cpp0x.centaur.ath.cx/temp.deduct.type.html ?

It seems you are far better than me at this, I'm trying to follow, but I guess I'll have to let you and voters decide.

Comment: @Max: I use N3290 from [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/prot/14882fdis/n3290.pdf)

Comment: Take a look at Richard Smith's answer.

Answer (score 8):

g++ is wrong. From C++11 [temp.deduct.type]p5:

> The non-deduced contexts are: [...]
>   - A function parameter for which argument deduction cannot be done because the associated function argument is [...] a set of overloaded functions, and [...] more than one function matches the function parameter type

This determination is made without regard to template parameters that might have been deduced elsewhere, so the fact that `T` must deduce as `int` is not relevant here. This makes the entire parameter `M (fun)(T)` a non-deduced context. Therefore `M` cannot be deduced, just as Clang claims.

g++ appears to incorrectly be using the '`T` = `int`' deduction from the first function parameter when determining whether the second parameter is a non-deduced context. Reversing the order of the function parameters causes g++ to reject the code too:

```
int A(double);
int A(int);
template<class M, class T>
M test(M (fun) (T), T input) {
  return fun( input );
}
int main( int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  test(A, 1);
  test(A, 1.2); 
}
```

Comment: This looks correct.  (One thing that confused me for a moment: the "function parameter" which is a non-deduced context is `M (fun)(T)`, not a parameter to `A`.  Even though the answer did explain that.)

Comment: This kind of thing is why I prefer using functors wherever possible instead of function pointers.